# Does "Deny log on locally" effect "Allow log on through terminal services"?

Tags: windows-server-2003, security

I am hardening a system and i am unsure about whether or not denying log on locally but allowing log on through terminal services will work. Does deny locally override the terminal services setting?

Comment: No it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Deny log on locally" only applies to someone trying to log in at the computer itself through the mouse and keyboard attached to it. If it's a virtual server, then logging in through the VM management console is the same thing. It's how you allow users to log into the server by remote, but still prevent them from logging in at the machine.